# webstorm 6.0.1 not starting in winxp in VMwareFusion

Tags: webstorm, vmware-fusion

I get the following error when i start webstorm in winXP in VMWare Fusion on a macbookpro. Please can some one help

config path \vmware-host\shared Folders.webstorm6\config is invalid 
IF you have modified the 'idea.config.path' property please make sure it is correct, otherwise please re-install the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that ${user.home} property is resolved to \vmware-host\shared Folders, and this path is not accepted by WS. You can try editing bin\idea.properties under the WebStorm installation directory and point the idea.config.path and idea.system.path to specific directories under your user account

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and was able to work around by moving the .exe file to launch the program to another directory.  Turns out, I had shared my desktop with my mac, so the working directory resolved to my physical machine, instead of the virtual one.

When I copied the executable (in my case, intellij idea) to a folder that was not shared between operating sytems then it launched correctly.